# Organizar tabla dentro de modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, datatables

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente con una tabla que me muestra unos datos almacenados en la base de datos, una vez que tengo cargado muchos registros la tabla se sale de control.

Mi idea es que la tabla tenga un scroll vertical, pero no se como ponerlo, probe con esto, pero no funciona:

```
style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;"
```

muestro como me queda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde ya, Muchas gracias a todos!!

Comment: Intenta ponerle ese style al contenedor donde esta tu datatable y ponle max-height no height

Comment: En lugar de auto usa scroll. Y en todo caso en el inspector fijate si no hay otra regla que lo esté anulando.

Comment: Esa modal es de bootstrap?

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, probare sus recomendaciones, avisare los resultados.

Comment: David, el modal que uso es de bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo funcionan en ie9+, Chrome 34+, Firefox 19+, Safari 7+, Android 4.4+ y iOS 6+

```
style="max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);overflow-y: auto";
```

no se si estas usando boostrap te recomiendo que le agregues [paginadores](https://librosweb.es/libro/bootstrap_3/capitulo_6/paginadores.html)
y que lo ordenes alfabéticamente.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probare

Comment: Copiando el codigo asi no me funciono, le agregue   Style= "display: block".  con eso funciono, pero un poco angosto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes de colocar los siguientes propiedades **CSS** al selector `.modal-body` así:

```
.modal-body{
  max-height:150px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```css
.modal-body{
  max-height:150px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Lo probare David, gracias

Comment: @DiegoArce te sirvio?

Comment: La verdad no me sirvio David, le agregue esto a la etiqueta y asi logre que funcione.  style=" display: block; max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);overflow-y: auto";